# What flavor of SOAP is defined by this WSDL, and how to consume it with PHP?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, ws-security

We have a PHP application which needs to connect to this SOAP web service—here's the WSDL: https://arixss.arifleet.com/QA/DriveAwayWS/DriveAwaySrvc.svc?wsdl

The vendor claims it uses "WS-Security (wsHttpBinding)". This doesn't mean much to me, as I don't have experience beyond "normal" unauthenticated SOAP. Furthermore, I understand there are probably several ways to implement WS-Security, and the vendor hasn't provided a full specification.

So far, thanks to the WSSoap class given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22367592/277303), I have been able to connect, authenticate, and run the `GetAllRequests` method successfully. However, I'm stuck when trying to run the `GetRequestDetail` method, because I don't know what kind of parameter argument to use. The vendor offers this snippet of .NET code as an example:

```
DriveAwayClient client = new DriveAwayClient();
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "…";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "…";
ARIRqst rqst = new ARIRqst();
rqst.RqstType = "ORDER";
rqst.OrderID = "12345";
string RequestDetail;
RequestDetail = client.GetRequestDetail(rqst);
```

This code can't be rewritten in PHP (at least using the WSSoap class) because I have no way of injecting a `ARIRqst` object using WSSoap. Furthermore, I wouldn't know how to instantiate a `ARIRqst` object, because I don't have access to a `ARIRqst()` class in PHP.

I thought if I knew more about the specific requirements of this web service, as defined by the WSDL—what its specific type is, and what authentication is used—I would have better luck finding an example in PHP which can consume it, or at least find the specifications so that I could write my own implementation.

**UPDATE:** To be specific, I ultimately just need to know how to format the request for this web service's `GetRequestDetail` method. Here's what I'm sending:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IDriveAway/GetRequestDetail</a:Action>
        <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:eacedde2-cec5-4da1-afbf-822fe2e92793</a:MessageID>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://arixss.arifleet.com/QA/DriveAwayWS/DriveAwaySrvc.svc?wsdl</a:To>
        <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>2014-04-08T23:20:00Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2014-04-08T23:25:00Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
            <c:SecurityContextToken xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc" u:Id="uuid-85c09ef0-83e1-417c-b9c7-5892798ee739-197">
                <c:Identifier>urn:uuid:24d56285-84f1-4c74-8093-5f72090ab92f</c:Identifier>
            </c:SecurityContextToken>
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1"/>
                    <Reference URI="#_0">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>[REDACTED]</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>[REDACTED]</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <o:Reference ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct" URI="#uuid-85c09ef0-83e1-417c-b9c7-5892798ee739-197"/>
                    </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <ns1:GetRequestDetail xsi:type="ns1:ARIRqst">
            <RqstType>ORDER</RqstType>
            <RqstID>1234</RqstID>
            <OrderID>1234-1</OrderID>
            <QuoteID>1</QuoteID>
        </ns1:GetRequestDetail>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And here is the response from the server, containing an `InternalServiceFault` of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" (which I assume means I'm not encoding the `ARIRqst` object correctly in the request):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher/fault</a:Action>
        <a:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:c0af2ed0-9afb-4c77-a09f-2463bf5cbc52</a:RelatesTo>
        <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>2014-04-08T23:20:26.872Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2014-04-08T23:25:26.872Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <s:Code>
                <s:Value>s:Receiver</s:Value>
                <s:Subcode>
                    <s:Value xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</s:Value>
                </s:Subcode>
            </s:Code>
            <s:Reason>
                <s:Text xml:lang="en-US">Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</s:Text>
            </s:Reason>
            <s:Detail>
                <ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
                    <InnerException i:nil="true"/>
                    <Message>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</Message>
                    <StackTrace>   at ARI.DriveAwayMgr.DriveAwaySrvc.GetRequestDetail(ARIRqst rqst) in d:\[REDACTED]\DriveAwaySrvc.svc.cs:line 189&#xD;
   at SyncInvokeGetRequestDetail(Object , Object[] , Object[] )&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp; outputs)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</StackTrace>
                    <Type>System.NullReferenceException</Type>
                </ExceptionDetail>
            </s:Detail>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Ugh... I feel for you.  SOAP is the *only* API mechanism I deplore.

Comment: Thanks, I feel better. You must be great with the ladies, empathizing rather than just trying to fix things. ;)

Comment: Well, I am gay, so... On a more relevant note, can SOAP be fixed?  I was just trying to express appreciation for your pain, dude, nothing more or less.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://soap.amazon.com/schemas3/AmazonWebServices.wsdl');
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
?>
```

From php.net.

Just insert the wsdl into the SoapClient call...it should return all methods and parameters...

You can wrap it in a try catch block also

Comment: Yes, that will display all methods and parameters. I have those. What I need is to know the WS-Security implementation details: what type of authentication is used? Are PKI keys and certificates being used? Do requests need to be signed? Encrypted? [WS-Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security) isn't supported by the built in PHP SoapClient, and there isn't much documentation or third-party tools for using WS-Security with PHP.